# Firefox crashes on startup

Tags: firefox, crash

After re-installing Ubuntu (14.04) Firefox crashes *every time* I turn it on. I open it, it crashes, reopens and then works. `about:crashes` says always the same, that there was a problem with `libgstflump3dec.so` module.

So, I already installed: `libgstreamer0.10-dev`, `libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev`, `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` from `ppa:mc3man/trusty-media` (the last one as described [in here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/get-firefox-and-phonon-gstreamer-to.html)), but none of this helped.

Another thing I already done is `apt-get purge firefox` and then reinstalled it - also with no luck.

Do you have any ideas on what could be wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not a bug of the firefox version you've installed (is it from a regular/official Ubuntu repository, or an odd custom PPA?) then it's most often a firefox profile problem.

Try these [instructions to start in "Safe Mode" with all addons disabled](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)
(Basically open the Help menu and select "Restart with Add-ons Disabled...")

Then proceed with the troubleshooting options on the above website:

- If the problem still happens in Safe Mode, it is not being caused by an extension or theme

  - [Troubleshoot and diagnose Firefox problems](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-and-diagnose-firefox-problems)
  - [Troubleshoot issues with plugins like Flash or Java to fix common Firefox problems](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-issues-with-plugins-fix-problems)
  - [Reset Firefox preferences to troubleshoot and fix problems](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-preferences-fix-problems)
- If the problem does not happen in Safe Mode, it is most likely because of an extension, theme or hardware acceleration.
  See the article [Troubleshoot extensions, themes and hardware acceleration issues to solve common Firefox problems](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-extensions-themes-to-fix-problems) for solutions

Comment: This instructions need Firefox running. Firefox doesn't start correctly and crashes.

Comment: @user3005629 That is correct, this question is about Firefox crashing, re-opening and then working. Yours is a different question. But at any rate, if you wanted to try using a different profile with your Firefox that often solves lots of problems. Try starting it with `firefox -p` and create/choose a different profile.